# how to Append an arrays values and keys to another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

IN PHP i have the following arrays.

[image: Array 1]

And i have this array:

[image: Array 2]

What i want to do is append the second array to the first one,
i tried doing it like so:

```
end($array1);
 foreach($array2 as $key => $value ){
 $array1[$key] = $value;

 }
```

With this result:

[image: New Array]

**My question is; How do i put the the  values and keys of the second array into the first one?**

Answer: due to the answer of Manikiran i now got the following array as a result:

[image: Solution]

Comment: If you need more information please ask me, i will stay online until the question is answered

Comment: In the first array the key is `campaign_id` while in the second one the key is `id`. Do you want to keep the key from the second array in the result?

Comment: can you add to your question what your new `array1` should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**array_merge()** is the function you are looking for. Try the following code:

```
$new_array=array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

For more information, check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Could the person who down voted my answer point out the reason for it?

Comment: i agree..they should not downvote post without reason.

Comment: @Manikiran . I've down voted your answer because what I've understood from the question, before being edited, your solution wasn't fit. But, of course, after edit is very clear what the op wants.. Is fully his fault for this down vote.. I will up vote your answer as soon as I can.. Thank you for understanding

Comment: @MateiMihai No worries pal, it always happens.